# Angular 2.0, getting HPE_INVALID_CHUNK_SIZE

Tags: angular, http

I am currently using Angular 2.0 for client and Spring Boot for server side.
Currently, I am facing an issue where client sends a post request to server and server sends a response as a json after 5 minutes and its a huge json. On the client side that is angular 2.0 , I am getting HPE_INVALID_CHUNK_SIZE and it gets closed. 
I have tried using the same http post request in postman and its works fine.
Can you anyone please help me with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I got into similar troubles if I did not send proper `Transfer-Encoding` or `Content-Length` http headers. Solution for me was to either send `Content-Length` or ommit it and send `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` instead.

Generally speaking whenever I got `HPE_INVALID_CHUNK_SIZE` error while doing with JavaScript first I do is checking headers I am sending to server.

I would recommend to examine headers sent by POST man and compare them to those sent by your angular app.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Transfer-Encoding#Directives