# webpack dev server proxy has an error : HPE_INVALID_CHUNK_SIZE

Tags: spring-boot, webpack, proxy, webpack-dev-server

I use webpack-dev-server on my project.
Project uses Spring boot + Tiles + Vue + webpack.

Environment:

```
OS: Mac OS
Node Version: 9.4.0
NPM Version: 5.6.0
Webpack Version: 4.25.1
webpack-dev-server Version: 3.1.10
```

In local environment, FE port use 8080 and webpack-dev-server port is 9090.
Bundled files by webpack are created in /front/static-dev/build/.
So, I use proxy options like below.

```
devServer: {
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:9090/front/static-dev/build/',
    port: 9090,
    proxy: {
        '/**': {
            target: 'http://localhost:8080',
            secure: false,
            changeOrigin: true
        }
    },
    open: true
}
```

After starting webpack-dev-server, static resources like (JSP, bundled js files, CSS files or image, ...) are loaded normally. However, whenever I request some api, webpack-dev-server occured same error. Error logs are like below.

```
[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy 
request /api/v1/users/name from localhost:9090 to 
http://localhost:8080 (HPE_INVALID_CHUNK_SIZE) 
(https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
```

After request some API, I checked logs on Eclipse and Api requests are normally being made. In Chrome Consloe log like below.

```
http://localhost:9090/api/v1/users/name net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED 502 (Bad Gateway)
```

I think the problems are in response part.
Searching HPE_INVALID_CHUNK_SIZE with Webpack in google, I can find no information.

How can I solve this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

I resolve this issue using Connection options.

```
        proxy: {
        '/**': {
            target: 'http://localhost:8080/',
            secure: false,
            changeOrigin: true,
            headers: {
                Connection: 'keep-alive'
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This error might be caused by wrong headers sent to your proxy. In case of any further problems you could try `Transport-Encoding: chunked` or set `Content-Length` http headers. You can see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55433376/996895